# Hopw to make sure you are working on latest version of SSRS Report from Report Server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I just created a Report Project with 1 .rdl in Visual Studio 2008. I then deployed the report to the SSRS Server and I can now see the report in the Report manager.

I made a change to the report using report builder 3.0.

Is there a way that I can "get latest version" from the report server of the .rdl when I open my report project in Visual Studio again?

I am guessing that 1 way would be to download the .rdl and add back (overwriting) to the report project but I am wondering if VS has a built in function to take care of this for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio is used to create and deploy reports, once they are deployed, there are no links between the report in Visual Studio and the Report Server, and there will never be. Think about it, you can deploy the report to X servers, so how could Visual Studio find which report you are talking about.

To ensure you are working on the latest version, you will have to download it and overwrite as you say, although I would compare it instead to see if there are changes not deployed.

If you are working with other developers that would potentially redeploy the report, then you can just check the last modification user of the report.

In all cases, I would strongly suggest to always check-in/commit when you deploy a report.

If you want to download several reports from the report server, then you could use a tool like [RSScripter](https://sqlserverfinebuild.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Install%20Reporting%20Services%20Scripter) for example.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in functionality in VS to attach to an SSRS instance and pull down the .rdl files. Since they can be moved, edited and deleted, outside of the designer there could be numerous issues with doing that. Just check all your local project files into source control and manually update if needed. Since I don't edit outside of VS I never had to deal with "pulling the latest version from ssrs". However, I have come across third party tools that may have functionality to make it easier.

If this is going to become a daily struggle for you then you may want to take the time now to automate the process using the [ReportExecution2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.aspx) or [ReportExecution2005](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2005.reportingservice2005.aspx) web service api.